# Passing argument through nohup command

Tags: bash, cron

I have my startup.sh file as below

```
echo "Kicking off the app..."
source ~/.bashrc
cd /qa/updateprocess/
nohup /opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -Xmx768m -Xms256m - 
Dlogging.config=/qa/updateprocess/logback.xml -jar /qa/updateprocess/update-service.jar -- 
spring.profiles.active=qa &> logs/console.log&
```

Below is how my cron tab which kicks off the above startup script each day:

```
0 0 * * * /qa/updateprocess/startup.sh
```

This jar file requires date as an input argument, my question is how do I pass in the data automatically to this?
I need to pass in date as current date minus 7 days i.e script has to run each time with last week's date.

Say, today is 2021-10-21 then it has to pass in 2021-10-14 as argument to this script automatically.

How do I achieve this? thanks in advance

Comment: `$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: For the "minus 7 days" part, look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-days-to-date-and-get-new-date-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints. I finally got it working.

```
echo "Today's date: $(date "+%Y-%m-%d")"
goback_days="7 days"
echo "Going back ${goback_days}: $(date -d $date" - ${goback_days}" "+%Y-%m-%d")"
input_date="$(date -d $date" - ${goback_days}" "+%Y-%m-%d")"

nohup /opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -Xmx768m -Xms256m - 
Dlogging.config=/qa/updateprocess/logback.xml -jar /qa/updateprocess/update-service.jar $input_date &> -- 
spring.profiles.active=qa &> logs/console.log&
```

This might help somebody.